# True/False Linear Algebra Question

Tags: linear-algebra

**Question:** Suppose that $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix with real number entries. Suppose that $Ax$ has the same length as $x$, for every vector $x$ in $\mathbb R^n$. Then $A$ is orthogonal.

**My Attempt:** True. I believe it's true because a matrix is orthogonal if it preserves the length of vectors.

$$\langle A\vec{v}, A\vec{v} \rangle = \langle \vec{v}, \vec{v} \rangle$$

The angle is also preserved.

I don't know how to really explain it better than this but I know this isn't the best way to go about it. Is there an easier way to prove this?

Comment: There are several definitions of orthogonal matrices (a matrix that preserves angles, a matrix whose columns form an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$, a matrix such that $AA^T=I$). All are equivalent, but which one can you use for the proof?

Comment: I can use the length preserving property. For every $A$ you have $$(Ax)^{T}(Ax) = x^{T}A^{T}(Ax) = x^{T}(A^{T}A)x = x^{T}Ix $$

Comment: My question is what is the definition of orthogonal matrix that you are using? (the one that you want to prove).

Answer (score 1):

I want to prove that the lengths are preserved. That means $\lVert{\vec{x}}\rVert = \rVert{A\vec{x}}\rVert $

Therefore 
$$\begin{align} 
  \lVert{A\vec{x}} \rVert^{2} & = A\vec{x}\cdot A\vec{x} \\
& = (A\vec{x})^{T}A\vec{x} \\
& = (\vec{x}^{T}A^{T})A\vec{x} \\
& = \vec{x}^{T}(A^{T}A)\vec{x} \\
& = \vec{x}^{T}\vec{x} \\
& = \vec{x} \cdot \vec{x} \\
& = \lVert \vec{x} \rVert^{2} \\ 
\end{align} $$

Comment: The questions asks for the converse.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that $A$ orthogonal means $A^T A=I$.

Let $B=A^T A-I$. Then
$$
\| Bx \|^2 = x^T B^T B x = x^T A^T A x - x^T x = \| Ax \|^2 - \| x \|^2 = 0
$$
Therefore, $Bx=0$ for all $x$, and so $B=0$.